# Python/Pandas: How do I combine two DataFrames, where one of the frames shall be a DataFrame within a cell of the other frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas DataFrames. Both DataFrames are time series with one common column (let's call it batchNumber) of the following structure:

```
[time = index, batchNumber, valueColumn, other fields]
```

The first DataFrame comprises one row per batchNumber, the second DataFrame comprises many rows per batchNumber, each row with an individual time step.

I would like to combine (on purpose I avoid "join" here as I am not sure if this would be the right technique) these two frames into one having a structure:

```
[time1, batchNumber1 = batchNumber2, value1, [(time2[0], value2[0]), (time[1], value[1]), (time[2], value[2]), ..., (time[N], value[N])], other fields1]
```

Hence, a kind of "DataFrame within a DataFrame". Is that possible? How can one achieve that?

Data in df1 looks like this, columns [value, batchNumber, timestamp, otherID]:

```
[[3.06130831419325e-05 1552608005236178640 '2019-03-15T00:00:05.236178688Z' 1552608005236178640]
[3.1214206203101214e-05 1552608010657198640 '2019-03-15T00:00:10.657198592Z' 1552608010657198640]
[2.9220824990100192e-05 1552608016078218640 '2019-03-15T00:00:16.078218752Z' 1552608016078218640]
[3.1036932744355974e-05 1552608021499238640 '2019-03-15T00:00:21.499238656Z' 1552608021499238640]
[2.9085449547509336e-05 1552608026920258640 '2019-03-15T00:00:26.92025856Z' 1552608026920258640]
        ...
```

Data in df2 looks like follows, columns [value, batchNumber, timestamp, otherID]:

```
[[512.5499877929688 1552608005236178640 '2019-03-15T00:00:05.236178688Z' 1552608005236178640]
 [512.7000122070312 1552608005236178640 '2019-03-15T00:00:05.236180736Z' 1552608005236178640]
 [513.0999755859375 1552608005236178640 '2019-03-15T00:00:05.236182528Z' 1552608005236178640]
 [513.0 1552608005236178640 '2019-03-15T00:00:05.236184576Z' 1552608005236178640]
 [513.5 1552608005236178640 '2019-03-15T00:00:05.236186624Z' 1552608005236178640]
 [512.8499755859375 1552608005236178640 '2019-03-15T00:00:05.236188672Z' 1552608005236178640]
 [513.3499755859375 1552608005236178640 '2019-03-15T00:00:05.23619072Z' 1552608005236178640]
 [512.9500122070312 1552608005236178640 '2019-03-15T00:00:05.236192768Z' 1552608005236178640]
 [513.2000122070312 1552608005236178640 '2019-03-15T00:00:05.23619456Z' 1552608005236178640]
 [513.2000122070312 1552608005236178640 '2019-03-15T00:00:05.236196608Z' 1552608005236178640]
 [512.8499755859375 1552608005236178640 '2019-03-15T00:00:05.23619...
```

As one can see, there are on batchNumber value in df1 and the same batchNumber many times in df2, creating a 1:n relation between the lines of df1 and df2.

I would like to have all lines of df2 matching the batchID of df1 as a subtable/list/DataFrame in a new cell added to df1, symbolically speaking:

```
df_new.row = df1.row + df2.subset(batchNumber(df2) == batchNumber(df1))
```

Comment: Seems like you may want a [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) on ('batchNumber', 'time')?

Comment: At least it sounds promising, but I am struggling with applying this to my problem...

Comment: Can you provide a [mvce] with two sample DataFrames? Just a few rows from each and some description of how you want the output to look?